# Velocity. Can't load my resources

Tags: java, maven, velocity

structure of my project:

```
-src
--main
---java
----makers
-----SomeClass
---resources
----htmlPattern.vm
```

How tell to SomeClass about htmlPattern. I try something like this:

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "file");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "resources");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "2");
    ve.init(properties);

    Template t = ve.getTemplate("htmlPattern.vm", "utf-8");
```

What's wrong? The IDE says:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'htmlPattern.vm'
```

Comment: Is this your exact project structure, because it should be `src/main/java`. So,your file should be under `src/main/resources`

Comment: What is mean under src/main/resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "file");
    properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    ve.init(properties);
```